# Bash directories going in the wrong place

Tags: bash, awk

I'm a bash noob so any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

What I'm trying to do is take the first column from `Students.txt` file in the input folder and create directories for them in the output folder.

My problem is that when I execute my script only 1 (the first `$stuID`) directory gets made inside the output folder. The rest goes into the main folder.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILECONTENT=`awk '{print $1}' input/Students.txt`    
for stuID in "${FILECONTENT[*]}"; do
 mkdir -p ./output/$stuID    
done
```

Comment: Show what is in `input/Students.txt`. Also using `*` instead of `@` makes it a single arg, although that doesn't matter anyway as `FILECONTENT` is not an array.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `while read` loop to extract the first field from each line and create the directory:

```
while read -r stu_id junk; do
    mkdir -p ./output/"$stu_id"
done < input/Students.txt
```